# Зачем нужен static class?

Tags: java, дизайн-языка

Статические переменные нужны для доступа к ним, без создания экземпляра класса. А вот зачем нужен static класс?

Answer (score 26):

Статическим классом в java может быть только вложенный класс.
Если класс отмечен как static, то он ведет себя, как обычный класс.

например, есть класс А, вложенный статический класс B и вложенный (нестатический) класс С:

```
public class A{

...
  static public class B{
  }

  public class C{
  }
}
```

и мы хотим создать экземпляры этих классов во "внешнем" коде

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A(); // обычный класс
       A.B b = new A.B(); // статический вложенный класс

       A.C c = a.new C(); // вложенный класс, связан с экземпляром А
       // A.C c = new A.C(); // синтаксическая ошибка (не скомпилится)
    }
}
```

или внутри статических методов класса А

```
public class A{

...
    static public class B{
    }

    public class C{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A(); // обычный класс
       A.B b = new A.B(); // статический вложенный класс

       A.C c = a.new C(); // вложенный класс, связан с экземпляром А
       // A.C c = new A.C(); // синтаксическая ошибка (не скомпилится)
    }

    public static void test() {
       A a = new A(); // обычный класс
       A.B b = new A.B(); // статический вложенный класс

       A.C c = a.new C(); // вложенный класс, связан с экземпляром А
       // A.C c = new A.C(); // синтаксическая ошибка (не скомпилится)
    }
}
```

На мой взгляд использование статического класса может быть уместно, как небольшой класс, который по смыслу тесно связан с "основным" внешним классом.

Например:

```
public class Tree{
    static public class Node{
    }
}
```

В этой ситуации так же можно вынести вложенный класс в обычный и переместить оба класса в отдельный package.

Единственным отличием вложенного статического класса от обычного, которое мне видится, - это более снисходительное отношение к видимости 
методов и полей между вложенным классом и его внешним классом.

Например:

```
public class A {

   private void privateMethod(){
      B b = new B();
      b.privateMethod(); // есть доступ к приватным методам/полям
   }

   static public class B {
      private void privateMethod(){
         A a = new A();
         a.privateMethod(); // есть доступ к приватным методам/полям
      }
   }   
}
```

Ссылка на документацию:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 11):

В основном для того, чтобы можно было создавать вложенные классы, объекты которых можно создавать, не создавая инстанса класса в котором он лежит.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что никто не упомянул о том, что статический класс не имеет ссылки не внешний, и таким образом можно избежать утечек памяти.

ГЦ просто не сможет снести класс из-за того, что ссылка на него (внешний класс) осталась.

Answer (score -2):

"Статическим классом в java может быть только вложенный класс" - есть вложенные(`static`) и внутрение, разница как и в обычном плане, `static` имеет доступ только к статичным полям